# Generate thumbnails using the whole Blender screen

Tags: file-browser, asset-browser

I know we can frame thumbnails for blend files using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+**numpad** <kbd>0</kbd>.  But how can we generate thumbnails that use the whole Blender screen? see image below with red arrow.

[image: img]

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-numpad-0 just aligns the active camera to the view. It doesn't actually produce a thumbnail. To produce a saved image of Blender's whole screen just use Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu.